# Virtual Address to Physical address translation in the light of the cache memory

Tags: caching, memory-management, operating-system, virtual-memory, tlb

I do understand how the a virtual address is translated to a physical address to access the main memory. I also understand how the cache memory works as well.

But my problem is in putting the 2 concepts together and understanding the big picture of how a process accesses memory and what will happen if we have a cache miss. so i have this drawing that will help me asks the following questions:

[click to see the image ( assume one-level cache)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/a9FC4.png)

1- Does the process access the cache with the exact same physical address that represent the location of byte in the main memory ?

2- Is the TLB actually in the first level of Cache or is it a separate memory inside the CPU chip that is dedicated for the translation purpose ?

3- When there is a cache miss, i need to get a whole block and allocated in the cache, but the main memory organized in frames(pages) not blocks. So does a process page is divided itself to cache blocks that can be brought to cache in case of a miss ?

4- Lets assume there is a TLB miss, does that mean that I need to go all the way to the main memory and do the page walk there , or does the page walk happen in the cache ?

5- Does a TLB miss guarantee that there will be a cache miss ?

6- If you have any reading material that explain the big picture that i am trying to understand i would really appreciate sharing it with me.

Thanks and feel free to answer any single question i have asked

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Yes.  The cache is not memory that can be addressed separately.  Cache mapping will translate a physical address into an address for the cache but this mapping is not something a process usually controls. For some CPU architecture it is completely controlled by the hardware (e.g. Intel x86).  For others the operating system would be expected to program the mapping.
2. The TLB in the diagram you gave is for virtual to physical address mapping.  It is probably not for the cache. Again on some architecture the TLBs are programmed whereas on others it is controlled by the hardware.
3. Page size and cache line size do not have to be the same as one relates to virtual memory and the other to physical memory. When a process access a virtual address that address will be translated to a physical address using the TLB considering page size. Once that's done the size of a page is of no concern. The access is for a byte/word at a physical address. If this causes a cache miss occurs then the cache block that will be read will be of the size of a cache block that covers the physical memory address that's being accessed.
4. TLB miss will require a page translation by reading other memory.  This process can occur in hardware on some CPU (such as Intel x86/x64) or need to be handled in software. Once the page translation has been completed the TLB will be reloaded with the page translation.
5. TLB miss does not imply cache miss.  TLB miss just means the virtual to physical address mapping was not known and required a page address translation to occur. A cache miss means the physical memory content could not be provided quickly.

To recap:

- the TLB is to convert virtual addresses to physical address quickly. It exist to cache the virtual to physical memory mapping quickly. It does not have anything to do with physical memory content.
- the cache is to allow faster access to memory. It is only there to provide the content of physical memory faster.

Keep in mind that the term cache can be used for lots of purposes (e.g. note the usage of cache when describing the TLB).  TLB is a bit more specific and usually implies a virtual memory translation though that's not universal.  For example  some DMA controllers have a TLB too but that TLB is not necessarily used to translate virtual to physical addresses but rather to convert block addresses to physical addresses.

Comment: Thank you @Robin for this elaborated answers

Comment: 1. Yes or No. Depends on cache type. Physically indexed, physically tagged (PIPT) caches would use only PA. Virtually indexed, virtually tagged (VIVT) uses only VA.  Others VIPT, PIVT use both PA and VA to get value from cache.

Comment: 2. TLB is a separate cache. I'm not aware about CPU architectures with TLB cache intersecting with other L1, L2, etc caches

Comment: 4. Not really. Translation would require *access* to translation tables. CPU access translation tables by PA, so in case of PIPT cache translation tables could be presented in cache as any other type of data. And TLB miss might be resolved w/o accessing main memory.